# What's the purpose of `Time_Key` in Fluent Bit parsers?

Tags: parsing, fluentd, fluent-bit

I'm new to learning Fluent Bit, and I can't wrap my head around the benefit of specifying the `Time_Key` field in a parser.

An example from the documentation is below, but I don't know what the point of defining this is.  By declaring `Time_Key` and a `Time_Format` it seems to take your timestamp field out of your log data and does what with it?

When I added this option to my own `parser.conf` and sent the logs to Splunk, my timestamp field doesn't even appear in Splunk, whereas it did before I added `Time_Key`.  I know you can set the `Time_Keep` option to bring it back, but why would it remove a timestamp field from your log in the first place?  Timestamp is something that seems useful to me. So, what am I missing?

From the [documentation](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/parsers/json),

---

```
[PARSER]
    Name        docker
    Format      json
    Time_Key    time
    Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S %z
```

The following log entry is a valid content for the parser defined above:

```json
{"key1": 12345, "key2": "abc", "time": "2006-07-28T13:22:04Z"}
```

After processing, its internal representation will be:

```json
[1154103724, {"key1"=>12345, "key2"=>"abc"}]
```

The time has been converted to Unix timestamp (UTC) and the map reduced to each component of the original message.

---

I have added the `Time_Key` field to my parser and have seen it remove the timestamp field from my log data.  I just don't know what the purpose of doing this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use `Time_Key' to point to the time field in your log entry, Fluent-Bit will use the parsing time for its entry instead of the event time from the log, so the Fluent-Bit time will be different from the time in your log entry.

If you use `Time_Key` and Fluent-Bit detects the time, Fluent-Bit will drop the original field. You can keep it by setting `Time_Keep On` in your `parser.conf`, which will result in duplicate data.